# SharePoint 2013 provider hosted app w/ADFS user converted authenticates to windows user no SAML user

Tags: adfs, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem, s2s

I have a High Trust Provider hosted app using the configuration and claims helper from [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/12/07/using-sharepoint-apps-with-saml-and-fba-sites-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) .

The app can authenticate as app only but when I pass in the user information I get "There was an error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. " The SharePoint logs show that my user is being resolved as the windows user not the SAML user. This is further proven by if I add the windows account the app will authenticate and provide me the user context. What am I doing wrong?

JWT token:

```
{
    "upn": "dpalfery@ssolab.local", 
    "nii": "trusted:adfs", 
    "aud": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/portal.ssolab.local@ab32783d-87a4-4705-ba23-ae2ec8134272", 
    "iss": "8a7656d9-a909-4304-9c3f-0320b175015e@ab32783d-87a4-4705-ba23-ae2ec8134272", 
    "exp": "1395592109", 
    "actortoken": "<decoded below>", 
    "nbf": "1395591509"
}
{
    "upn": "dpalfery@ssolab.local", 
    "identityprovider": "trusted:ADFS", 
    "iss": "8a7656d9-a909-4304-9c3f-0320b175015e@ab32783d-87a4-4705-ba23-ae2ec8134272", 
    "smtp": "dpalfery@ssolab.local", 
    "trustedfordelegation": "true", 
    "exp": "1455591509", 
    "nameid": "8a7656d9-a909-4304-9c3f-0320b175015e@ab32783d-87a4-4705-ba23-ae2ec8134272", 
    "nbf": "1395591509", 
    "aud": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/portal.ssolab.local@ab32783d-87a4-4705-ba23-ae2ec8134272"
}
```

SharePoint Log:

> 03/23/2014 10:37:45.70    w3wp.exe (0x0B1C)   0x282C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Application
>   Authentication    ahkpt   Medium  SPApplicationAuthenticationModule
>   Authentication finished successfully for user:0#.w|ssolab\dpalfery and
>   actor:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|8a7656d9-a909-4304-9c3f-0320b175015e@ab32783d-87a4-4705-ba23-ae2ec8134272    401c809c-043a-2027-b3cc-8517dffcb09a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify enough info to be 100% sure, but it is likely one of the following:

- Need to specify -IsTrustBroker when creating the SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer
- User is not found in the user profile application (discussed in Steve's post)
- The identity claim is not unique in the user profile application. (Steve explicitly calls this out -- cannot have both claim user and windows user.)

Comment: Thank you Paul for providing such timely advice! yes it was number three, I had not set the Claims User Identifier property in the UPA properties. For the next guy here is the blog that Paul refers too. http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/08/08/mapping-user-profiles-for-saml-users-with-an-ad-import-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx